# Corporate Gmail (G Suite) login requires phone verification using non-existent phone (number)

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Logging into an Gmail email account, under corporate G Suite. For security reasons, Gmail insist on tapping onto 2-digit number, sent to a phone, which has not been set up in the first place. It does not say to which number this number is being sent, either. The "Can't use your phone?" option shows "Go back and use phone" (yeah, smart move, Google). I would need to tak classes on how to find my way through the overcomplicated security setting for the whole organisation in the management console. Also, I can't see a way to get around this in the per-user setting. Please help. Probably a way to set up a new verification phone number / device would do it (?)

EDIT: I did check related Q&A, but none of them work, since a) I do not have access to the account directly, b) it is a G Suite account

[image]

Comment: Have you already contacted the domain admin or if you are the domain admin have you already send a support ticket directly to Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This account could be added on a phone or a tablet, there are different options to verify the user. I would recommend to check "[verify a user's identity with extra security](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6002699?hl=en)" so you will understand when and why they will appear and how to disable, this is a login challenge that can be disabled for 10 minutes for you to access without requesting any 2step verification.